# Angular dropdown set default value is overlapping another value

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am facing an issue. I am using angular dropdown directive for custom select box.
[here](https://github.com/jseppi/angular-dropdowns) is the git repo for dropdown.

When ever i change the dropdown's value from any event , it replace the value for next selected value.

steps to reproduce

1. clickme : it will set option3 in DDL
2. now change it option2
3. again open the DDL , now it have replaced the option3 to option2

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the fiddle link?

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/deveshsinghal22/HB7LU/3701/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes in the fiddle please check this [Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/madhust/HB7LU/3703/)

```
 $scope.change = function()
{
    $scope.ddSelectSelected ={ text: $scope.ddSelectOptions[0].text,
                              someprop:     $scope.ddSelectOptions[0].text}

}
```

Comment: Thanks madhu,
You saved my day.
but should we consider this as directive bug or not?

Comment: No it is not a bug. We assigned the scope variable `ddSelectOptions[0]` directly to another scope variable `ddSelectSelected` and hence changes in `ddSelectSelected` reflected in `ddSelectOptions` also...